# QT insert widget inside an other widget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qwidget, qchart

I've created an UI with qt Creator,in this UI there is just a button and a widget (let's call it respectively button and char_container);
I need to add a chartview programmatically inside the chart_container.
I didn't change the default layout.

I've tried the following code,but it does not work:

```
void MainWindow::button_slot(){
    QtCharts::QChart *chart = new QtCharts::QChart();
    QtCharts::QChartView *chartView = new QtCharts::QChartView(chart);
    chartView->setParent(ui->chart_container);
    this.repaint();
}
```

Comment: You still need to add your chartview to MainWindow (just setting parent is not enough, AFAIK).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best way to add a widget inside another is to use a layout, as I show below:

```
//on constructor
ui->chart_container->setLayout(new QVBoxLayout);


void MainWindow::button_slot()
{
    QtCharts::QChart *chart = new QtCharts::QChart();
    QtCharts::QChartView *chartView = new QtCharts::QChartView(chart, ui->chart_container);
    ui->chart_container->layout()->addWidget(chartView);
}
```

Comment: I needed to add this lines beacause QT Creator doesn't add a layout automatically,so i got a sigsegv exception                                                                   QGridLayout *gridLayout = new QGridLayout;
    ui->chart_container->setLayout(gridLayout);

Comment: I've solved it,after clicking on the button,i just added a layout to the chart_container,before i got a sigsegv on the pointer returned by ui->chart_container->layout()